# Framework for runtime code updates?

Tags: php

I'm looking into methods of reducing maintenance downtime for a certain application.

One thing I could do, is make use of anonymous functions in a way that allows me to re-include a file with a new function definition during runtime. That way the application behaviour can be patched at runtime.

I'm wondering if there are any frameworks out there that would be helpful in implementing this behaviour on a large scale through out an application.

I'm thinking it could help with things like keeping track of which functions are loaded from which files, when/how often to reload them and similar tasks.

Comment: Are you actually asking for deployment tools?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Not really, though I suppose that could also be a part of it. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'd suspect this is unusual, since it's not typically a problem with the way PHP scripts are run.

Comment: Probably true, but still worth asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this open for now, but since I can't find anything at this time, I've started my own project: [PHP - Reloaded](https://github.com/letharion/reloaded)